can someone tell me why this auto hotkey script doesn't work anymore?
This script is something someone made for me. I cannot get a hold of him/her anymore. Here is what the script does.
I have multiple clients. Each has their own folder. x:\dropbox\law\cases\ [client name]
Within their folder, they each have an excel document named info. the excel document has multiple sheets within it. Those sheets are named opposing party, court, witnesses, family etc.
The idea behind the script is to allow the user to easily and rapidly select information the user will frequently need to insert into documents.
I also have an excel document titled clients.xls. that document is in the main case directory x:\dropbox\cases\clients.xls. it contains information about each client such as DOB, SSN, phone, etc.
The first part of the below script works. Hitting control plus numpad [#] inserts the correct information. but the problem occurs when I attempt to pull information from the info excel documents. For instance, hitting alt+numpad1 brings up the opposing party dialog box as it should. And I can select which opposing party I want to pull information from. I can then select the type of info I want such as address etc.
The problem is, where the code once took the selected item and pasted/sent it to whatever document I had open at the time, now it does nothing.
Nothing has changed in the script. I am too ignorant to make any changes.
Can anyone help me figure out why it is not working?
    filesPath := A_ScriptDir ; "x:\dropbox\law\cases\cases"

    ; Sheet names inside info.xlsx
    sheets := ["Children", "Third Parties", "Experts", "Witnesses", "Doctors", "Court", "Family", "Opposing",     "Opposing Witnesses"]

    init() ; Read Excel files at script load

    ; When Excel files change...
    ^f11::init() ; Read them again

    ; Select a Client
    f12::createGui("Client", -1)

    ; Client info
    ^numpad1::clientInfo(1) ; Name
    ^numpad2::clientInfo(2) ; Address
    ^numpad3::clientInfo(3) ; Phone
    ^numpad4::clientInfo(4) ; Email
    ^numpad5::clientInfo(5) ; Fax
    ^numpad6::clientInfo(6) ; DoB
    ^numpad7::clientInfo(7) ; SSN
    ^numpad8::clientInfo(8) ; Date of Injury
    ^numpad9::clientInfo(9) ; Wedding Date

    ^numpad0::clientInfo(9) ; Matter Link

    ; second part where i assume the problem is 

; Relational info

    !numpad1::createGui("Opposing", 1)

    !numpad2::createGui("Court"   , 1)

    !numpad3::createGui("Doctors", 1)

    !numpad4::createGui("Children", 1)

    !numpad5::createGui("Family", 1)

    !numpad6::createGui("Third Parties", 1)

    !numpad7::createGui("Opposing Witnesses", 1)

    !numpad8::createGui("Witnesses", 1)

    !numpad9::createGui("Experts", 1)


    ; End of configuration


    action()

    {

        global

        Gui Submit

        RegExMatch(A_GuiControl, "(\w+)_(\d)_(\d+)", match)

        ; match1 = rootName

        ; match2 = 0=fields, 1=data

        ; match3 = button#

        if match2

        {

            %match1%Id := match3

            if (match1 != "Client")

                createGui(match1, 0)

        }

        else

        {

            row := match1 "Id"

            SendInput % "{Raw}" clientData[clientId][match1].data[row][match3]

        }

    }


    clientInfo(field)

    {

        global

        if !clientId

            return createGui("Client", -1)

        SendInput % "{Raw}" clientData[clientId][field]

    }


    createGui(rootName, data)

    {

        global

        if (rootName = "Client")

            branch := clientData

        else if !clientId

            return createGui("Client", -1)

        else if data

            branch := clientData[clientId][rootName].data

        else ; fields

            branch := clientData[clientId][rootName].fields

    if !branch ; Client didn't have requested sheet
        return

    Gui New, +ToolWindow +AlwaysOnTop
    Gui Font, s11
    for i, node in branch
        Gui Add, Button, % "w140 h35 gAction v" rootName "_" !!data "_" i
            , % IsObject(node) ? node[1] : node
    clientName := clientId ? clientData[clientId][1] : "Select a Client"
    if (rootName != "Client")
        clientName .= " > " rootName
    Gui Show,, % clientName
}

init()
{
    global
    book := ComObjGet(filesPath "\clients.xlsx")
    sheet := book.Worksheets[1]
    clientData := clientId := ""
    readSheet(sheet, clientData)
    book.Close(false)
    for i, client in clientData
    {
        file := filesPath "\" client[1] "\info.xlsx"
        if !FileExist(file)
        {
            MsgBox % 0x10|0x40000, Error, % "Error loading info.xlsx for " client[1]
            clientData.Delete(i)
            continue
        }
        book := ComObjGet(file)
        for j, sheetName in sheets
        {
            try
            {
                sheet := book.Worksheets[sheetName]
                data := fields := ""
                readSheet(sheet, data, fields)
                clientData[i, sheetName, "data"] := data
                clientData[i, sheetName, "fields"] := fields
            }
        }
        book.Close(false)
    }
    book := sheet := ""
}

readSheet(sheet, ByRef rows, ByRef headers := "")
{
    headers := {}
    for cell in sheet.Range("A1:Z1")
    {
        if cell.value
        {
            colNum := A_Index
            colLtr := Chr(64 + A_Index)
            headers[A_Index] := cell.value
        }
        else break
    }
    rows := {}
    i := col := line := 0
    for cell in sheet.Range("A:" colLtr)
    {
        if Mod(++i, colNum) = 1
            col := 1
            , line++
        else col++
        if line = 1
            continue
        if cell.value
            rows[line - 1, col] := cell.value
        else if col = 1
            break
    }
}

GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
    Gui Destroy
return


I am sorry if the code is not formatted correctly. I am blind and have a hard time determining alignment of things sometimes

I think, if you'd like help, you will need to post links to some sample files (with dummy data and client names etc redacted). You might have more luck posting on the AutoHotKey forums here: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/
